# How to activate service worker on page reload in firefox?

Tags: service-worker, firefox-developer-tools

I am working on an app using a service worker. However, whenever I make edits to the service worker code and refresh the web page in Firefox, the updated version is not activated. Is there a way to force the activation of the updated version of my service worker on page reload, similar to the `Update on reload` option in Chrome? I have attached an image of the Chrome option for reference:

[image]